# Suppose $h,k \in G$ with $h\sim_{G} k$. Prove that there are $f,g \in G$ such that $h=fg$ and $k=gf$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So me being the dummy that I am, proved the converse direction thinking that that was sufficient, but upon careful reading over my proof, I realised that it wasn't good enough.

In terms of thought processes here, from definition we know that there exists an $r \in G$ such that $rhr^{-1}=k$. But then I just simply get stuck here and don't know how to finish this off. Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g = r$, $f = hr^{-1}$. Then $k = rhr^{-1} = gf$ and $h = hr^{-1}r = fg$.

Comment: Thanks! What was your motivation of choosing $f$ and $g$ like you did? Or was it just based on intuition?

Comment: @thesmallprint Given that $rhr^{-1} = k = gf$, there were only two sensible choices, the other being $g = rh$ and $f = r^{-1}$.